# How to use makecert to create a X509 certificate accepted by WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security, x509, makecert

Can anyone provide me with an example on how to create a self signed certificate, which would be accepted by the following code:

```
        ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass));

        var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, true);
        //security
        tcpbinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new BWUserNamePasswordValidator();
        svh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode =UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
        svh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = BookmarkWizSettings.TcpBindingCertificate;
        ....
        svh.Open();
```

I've used

```
makecert -pe myCertificate
```

and

```
makecert -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r signroot.cer -a sha1 -n "CN=Dev Certification Authority" -ss my -sr localmachine
```

and

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Client" -ss MyApp -sky Exchange
```

and I've tried to generate the certificate with BouncyCastle, but every time I'm getting following exception:

```
It is likely that certificate 'CN=Dev Certification Authority' may not have a 
private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access 
rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail.
```

and the inner exception is null.

There's likely a trick to it, but I'm not getting it.

How do I generate a proper certificate for my WCF service??

Comment: Take a look at this how to link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx

Comment: This link was the most helpful for me setting up mine. It walks through all the steps. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me for framework 4.0:
It is important first
**to install your certificate manually as trusted certificate in your LocalMachine**
In order to do this you can install it simply from internet explorer by opening the server location.

and second
**to respond to the server error, because of the self sign certificate**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Security;
namespace WCFSelfSignCert
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //You have to install your certificate as trusted certificate in your LocalMachine 

        //create your service client/ procy
        using (MyProxy.ServiceClient client = new MyProxy.ServiceClient())
        {

            //server certification respond with an error, because doesnt recognize the autority
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnServerValError;


            //Assign to self sign certificate
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            StoreName.Root,
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
            "MY custom subject name"); //SubjectName(CN) from  certificate

            //make a test call to ensure that service responds
            var res = client.echo("test");

            Console.WriteLine(res);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public static bool OnServerValError(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        //mute the error, or provide some custom validation code
        return true;

        //or more restrictive 

       // if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
        //{


        //    return true;
       // }
       // else
        //{

       //    return false;
       // }
    }

   }
}
```